# Como pegar os valores do formulário antes do submit com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, formulário

Tem como, antes do formulário ser enviado, eu pegar os valores de cada input do formulário usando o jQuery?

Comment: sim, só tratar o evento `submit`,  e dependendo do que precisa fazer com os valores, pode simplesmente serializar o form, algo assim `var valores = $("form").serializeArray()`

Comment: Sim, com [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Legal, pelo que entendi o serialize vai trazer tudos os campos que posso colocar em uma variável né? Aí eu uso split pra separar o valor de cada campo?

Comment: Vc quer os valores separados numa array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando [.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) você irá criar um array de objetos onde cada objeto terá dois pares de valores:

```
[{
   "name": "nome do elemento",
   "value": "valor do elemento",
}]
```

Por exemplo, se eu tenho o input:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="Fulano de Tal">
```

O resultado seria:

```
[{
   "name": "nome",
   "value": "Fulano de Tal",
}]
```

Se você quiser pegar apenas os `value` dos objetos e guardar numa outra array, basta usar `for...of`. Exemplo:

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var valores = []; // array para guardar os valores
   for(var valor of $(this).serializeArray()){
      valores.push(valor.value);
   }
   console.log(valores);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
   <input type="text" name="nome" value="Fulano de Tal">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="email" value="fulano@site.com">
   <br>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: show, é isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado!